# Out of memory error while processing large json

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, memory-management, google-cloud-storage

I have a spring boot application running on appengine. The service has to work with large json files stored on google cloud storage. The json files are usually ~50MB. While I do some processing on the json and then again save to Google Cloud Storage. I use `org.json.JSONObject` for storing json. My code to save the json is as follows.

Everything works well but at the end, it goes out of memory while saving the file.

```
    public void save(JSONObject json, String partnerBlob) throws IOException {
        gcpStorageService.pushBlob(bucket, blob, json.toString().getBytes());
    }
```

The exception stack trace is as follows

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1054) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE] at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE] at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE] at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE] at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE] at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-
9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE] at 
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE] at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar!/:9.0.21] at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.5.RELEASE] at
```

Comment: check your jvm mermory xms and xmx

Comment: What is your scaling option and your machine type on App Engine?

Comment: Scaling is auto. Instance type is F4_1G on appengine standard with java11 runtime

Comment: On average, how many requests per second does your application engine service serve?

Comment: @JAHDZP not much. Hardly 10 requests an hour

Comment: @tonyallen I had bad experiences with java running spring boot, but maybe this answer can help you to avoid memory lack

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61621526/11529321